# Can't figure out to let Xdebug work in combination with PhpStorm and XAMPP

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I followed this steps, recommended by Xdebug based on `phpinfo()`:

- Download `php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-5.6-vc11.dll`
- Move the downloaded file to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Update `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and change the line
- `zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-5.6-vc11.dll`
- Restart the web server

I also unchecked the 'ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations in PhpStorm. In PhpStorm port 9000 is configured. This port isn't used by an other application.

In the `php.ini` file I listed the following configuration:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

The DLL file exists.

I also enabled the debug functionality in chrome via the xdebug addon.

Which step do I miss?

Comment: FYI: xdebug 2.4 has stability issues (based on my personal experience) -- for PHP 5.6 I recommend sticking to xdebug 2.3.2 (not even 2.3.3)

Comment: Also -- have a look at debugging tutorials: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to want to set `xdebug.remote_enable = 1` or the remote debugging will be disabled.

Also, set the remote debug port phpStorm is set to use:
`xdebug.remote_port=9000`  (I'm assuming port 9000, it's the default, but check phpstorm)

To debug every request (if you don't have the chrome plugin for a browser for example) use `xdebug.remote_autostart = on`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes the default port is 9000. I added both lines to the xdebug configuration part in my php.ini file. Unfortunately this hasn't solve the issue. I do use the Xdebug chrome extention.

Do I miss something else?

Comment: I use firefox, so I'm unsure of what's needed for the chrome extension.  2 other things you could try: 1.) change the host to 127.0.0.1 2.) turn on the remote_autostart so every request trys to start debugging regardless of signal from plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried to turn on the remote_autostart. Again no debug activity. I like to try your first suggestion. Where do I exactly need to change this? Only in the php.ini file?

Comment: Thank you, I was convinced of the fact that xdebug.remote_autostart was on. This did the job. Thank you.